# Given a number n, divide that into 16 groups of linear increasing value with the sum n

Tags: php, algorithm, math

So I'm building this tool and for part of it you input an integer n. On submit, the tool returns an array with 16 values, each one increasing, following a linear pattern. For the most basic example, inputting 136 returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16].

The solution does not have to return whole numbers, so the array can contain decimals. The solution should also be able to be scaled in such a way that you could make a "steeper" increase as needed.

Wasn't sure of the best way to do this. I'm working on this in PHP, but any language is fine as long as I could replicate it in PHP.

Comment: Your problem seems to be best suited to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ or even https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: "Scaled"? "Steeper"? It sounds as if you want the function to take a second parameter; what is it?

Comment: I actually needed a few use cases but didnt have solid numbers yet, so I wasn't sure how to work it into the question. I suppose the second parameter would be the amount of difference between each step. I'm not sure if that would be represented by a percentage or what. The closest I can describe it: if it were a graph pertaining to y=mx +b, for example, it'd be the slope, m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be trivial.  Divide your number N (136 in your example) by the quantity Q (16) of numbers to be generated; that's the center of the range.  For a given step size S (1), the low end of the range is `N/Q - S*(Q-1)/2`.

Comment: So let's say I wanted to have the values between each step to be larger, would I be able to use the same method? For instance, given the same example above, instead of the step size being 1, I needed it to be 2. That would mean the first value would be some decimal less than one, with larger increments. I assume the center point would remain the same? How might I go about doing that given the equation?

Comment: The step size is S in my formula; plug in whatever value you want.  It doesn't change the center point at all, as the larger values above the center are exactly counterbalanced by the lower values below center.

Comment: Ooh, I'm a dummy, I was reading step S(1) rather than step size equal to 1. Thank you!